# REST API with JSON in iPhone

Tags: objective-c

I want to parse REST API with JSON is there any Best Example or Tutorial so help me...... Like I want to post request like Login and Register and then parse Feed using REST API.....  I am using below code to post request

```
NSString *email = @"*******";
NSString *password = @"******";
NSString *apikey = @"********";
NSString *loginURL = @"***************";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginURL];

NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"apikey\":\"%@\",\"email\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}", apikey, email, password];

NSData *JSONBody = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
loginRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
loginRequest.HTTPBody = JSONBody;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:loginRequest
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                           NSLog(@"resp:%@",response);
                           // Manage the response here.

                       }];
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the JSON response, you will need to implement

```
id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data];
```

in your completionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

To get NSDictionary object from server response you may use :

```
NSDictionary *myDict  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

After that you can get objects and keys from myDict

The good tutorial you can find here http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/

Comment: Hi would you please send me Link that having example to Send JSON request and parse Response..... using REST API....

Comment: @hirentank this link is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSDictionary *sampledict = @{@"email":email,@"password":password,@"apikey":apikey};
 NSData *dataJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sampledict options:0 error:NULL];

NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
loginRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
loginRequest.HTTPBody = dataJson;
//add these lines
[loginRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[loginRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//remaining is the same in your code
```

Comment: Hi This give me response like                                      dict :{
    message = "Cannot consume content type";
    status = failed;
}